# Where in the .NET Source Code are keywords defined

Tags: c#, .net

I'm browsing the .NET source code reference (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) in an effort to find the codefiles in which keywords are defined.  Specifically, I'm interested in how `await` in the TPL is defined/implemented, but I'd also like to browse the internal implementation of other keywords at some time.

Doing a search for the string "await" on their reference site above only returns class, property, and field names that contain the string "await" (e.g., `class AwaitTaskContinuation`).

I realize this seems like a basic question, but I can't find any information elsewhere on this.

Comment: Probably keywords are directly defined in the compiler. Some of them being only syntactic sugar may exist only in the compiler.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/6be7f048e3cbb7a48cddcdef33d274ab40d3f799/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/SyntaxKindFacts.cs#L807

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ provides source code for the .NET Framework libraries (for .NET Core use https://source.dot.net/) it does not "define" keywords.

In particular case of `await` - it is syntactic sugar which is handled by the compiler ([Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/)) and you can try to search how it desugars it to actual code in the [github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) repo.

Or (I would say better, at least in the beginning) use some C# decompilation tool. There is online one https://sharplab.io/ (handles decompilation to C#, IL and even JIT Asm) - [example decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEECsBuWIDMyyIGFEBvWRc5XEADmQDZEBZACgEpEBeAPmQE56AdAE0AlgFMANgBM2mGAF8gA=) for the following code:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class C {
    public async Task M() => await Task.Yield();
}
```